# Fetching all data in a row from teradata using unix

Tags: unix, teradata

I am trying to fetch all data in a row in teradata with unix

i am not getting all the data in a row. It is only EXPORTING half of the data into txt file in each row

I am using

```
bteq <<EOF
.logmech ldap
.logon IP/user_name,password
.EXPORT REPORT FILE=test.txt
    .SET RECORDMODE OFF;
    .SET WIDTH 65531;
.Set Titledashes off;

 select requesttext(title '') from abc.tb 


.export reset; 
.LOGOFF;
.EXIT;
EOF
```

I have used maximum width but still i am not able to fetch entire row it is only fetching half of the row.
My each row has huge data

Comment: Can you provide the column definition for `requesttext`?

Comment: Hi @Rob Paller thanks for the reply. My column definaltion is RequestText VARCHAR(12500) CHARACTER SET UNICODE NOT CASESPECIFIC FORMAT 'X(255)',

Comment: I think`FORMAT x(255)` is the demon :-) coz it will return just starting `255` characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for my question

i have used

```
select requesttext (format 'x(12500)')(title '') from abc.tb
```

and it is now fetching all the data

Thank to all for your response

Answer (score 1):

Above case has been simulated on `bteq` and below is the finding.

If column definition has `FORMAT 'X(255)'` clause, only first `256` characters are exported otherwise all data are exported.

> Sample Scenario

**Scenario 1:** Table has a row having `1017` characters. only first `255` characters are exported.

*Table definition as below*

```
CREATE SET TABLE abc ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      c1 VARCHAR(12500) CHARACTER SET UNICODE NOT CASESPECIFIC FORMAT 'X(255)')
PRIMARY INDEX ( c1 );
```

**Scenario 2:** Table has a row having `1017` characters. whole row is exported.

*Table definition as below*

```
CREATE SET TABLE abcd ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      c1 VARCHAR(12500) CHARACTER SET UNICODE NOT CASESPECIFIC)
PRIMARY INDEX ( c1 );
```